# WP7 inter process communication

Tags: windows-phone-7, agent, inter-process-communicat

I am building an music player using Background audio player agent on WP7. I want to enable communication between the UI part and the agent part. Many [guides](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpukcoe/archive/2012/02/10/background-audio-in-windows-phone-7-5-part-2.aspx) suggest using isolate storage, but I think that is not a good way

Is there any way to enable **inter-process communication** in Windows Phone 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8 SDK, we can now use system-wide Mutex object.

It seems the foreground App and Background Agent run as separate *processes* on the phone.  So even when you instantiate the same class, each process has a different *instance*.

The best solution I know about so far is to have each process map the "shared" data structure to an Isolated Storage file, then use a system wide Mutex (named Mutex) to prevent one process from reading the file when the other is writing it.  It'll be simpler if one process is always the writer of the data structure, so it never has to worry about merging in changes made by the other process asynchronously.  If each process must be the writer of some portion of the data structure, the usual case, consider separating those portions into separate data structures and separate Isolated Storage files, with one process reading one file and writing the other and the other process writing the first and reading the second.  (all reads and writes within mutex.  Use *same* mutex for both files and both processes to avoid deadlocks.)

Comment: thanks, I also know this before, but I think its just workaround. I want real inter-process communication

Comment: Do you need more than is provided by BackgroundAudioPlayer? This allows foreground to send fastforward, change track, etc. commands to the audio player running in background.  It's very specialized for media playback.  If you need something more general than this, the only other thing I can suggest is TCP sockets, but you'd need Socket.Listen(), which is only available in WP8 (your question mentions WP7 specifically).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

phoneApplicationPage.State

Comment: PhoneApplicationPage is not available in agent