# Windows Phone inter-app communication through common share library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8.1 on Visual Studio 2013 with `C#`, I created a .dll library file which save some data, same `.dll` I used in another app.

My requirement is on the basis of same `.dll` file, I should communicate with another app. Like in case of Android, we have broadcast receiver which make a request internally and data sharing between two apps is easily possible. Is there any functionality in Windows Phone development as well which make this task feasible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 inter process communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780850/wp7-inter-process-communication)

Comment: more reference to this - http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/03/27/using-named-events-to-coordinate-foreground-apps-and-background-agents/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you save anything in isolated storage, it's isolated to that app. No other app can access it, regardless if they share the same libraries (.dll).
[Share data between Windows Phone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948521/share-data-between-windows-phone-apps)

Two ways of communicating between apps:

**Deep Linking**

You can use deep linking to open one app from another and pass values to the app.

You can lunch another apps with with a URI string and Associated Files.
[Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

**Saving and retrieving Data from a Web Service or Cloud Storage**

Apps can share data between them by by uploading data to cloud storage, when the second app opens, it can check for new data.

This will obviously only work if the device has data connection.

Comment: Thanks for reply Johan, is it any how possible common library fetch the data from App A silently and pass this data to another app B who is sharing the same library.
My requirement is very much based on common library communication for two apps, please reply.. 
Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: @Anil Chahal No, not that I am aware off. Unless you implement a silent push to the app which is do-able in iOS and Android, but not sure about WP8